# How can I share a post from Facebook on Android with other apps?

Tags: facebook

Facebook for Android doesn't seem to have any ability to provide a permalink for a post, or a share possibility for other apps. It only allows to send via Facebook Messenger, which obviously is useless. Also Facebook's save feature is useless if I want to use for example Pocket.

Did I miss something? Is there any hack? Alternative application?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending it to yourself via messenger? since the facebook can actually make you send yourself a msg... try doing that, that might be the answer.

P.S. I can't comment cause I still don't have 50 reps.. hate that kind of thing here...